# Panel Generalized Method of Moments

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value

[image]I run this regression including Lag 1 of the independent variables on the instrument list, but get confused how to interpret the overall significant. Kindly assist me to check what I will use to interpret the overall significant of this model. The result have J statistics but without J statistics P value. Is the model okay for interpretation? The data is panel on GMM. Thanks in advance. J statistics is 9.77E-11